# MySQL Workbench - how to see more than 1 column from related table?

Tags: mysql-workbench

When entering rows in MySQL workbench, if you're entering a FK value, a drop down appears and it shows (it seems like) the first column after the other table's PK. Is there a way to specify which column or columns to show? Ideally, I'd like it to display a few columns. It would help a lot with data entry.

Comment: You mean the drop down in the `referenced column`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop down list in the `referenced column` shows all fields:

[image]

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I meant when you are entering data in a column that references another table. It shows a dropdown menu of possible values from the referenced table.